# Same font for title of abstract and ToC, ToC itself, and all titles in the text

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, titles

I have the following problem:
The title of the `abstract`, the title of the `ToC`, and all the titles in the text (`chapter`, `section`, `subsection`,...) have an **Arial-style** font type. Somehow I managed to change the `ToC` to the same font as the **TimesNewRoman**-like text font style. How to I do this for the `abstract` and `ToC` titles as well as the other titles?

Below I have added all my settings. Since I am new to writing in `TeX` (using `TeXStudio`) I do not know yet how to do it properly. The three reports that I have done so far looked nice and as I wanted them - despite the dozens of warnings sometimes. All that counts for me is that it looks as I want it to...and I managed this so far. Therefore, I do not see why I should study perfect `TeX`ing for weeks besides not having time for this. Is this a doable way for TeX-beginners or is it absolutely wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,abstracton]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{caption}
\addto\captionsngerman{%                            
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,amsbsy,latexsym}
%\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} %Chemie-Package
\providecommand{\e}[1]{\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}
%\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage{enumerate,url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{titling}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents} %only functioning when babel not used
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\addto\captionsngerman{%
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

%% Control the fonts and formatting used in the table of contents.
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

%% Aesthetic spacing redefined
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}



\begin{document}

\title{\LARGE Abc \\ [1em] \huge \textbf{AbcAbc}}
\author{Hans Muster \hspace{1cm} Hans Muster2}
\date{\\[1em] {Date 2014} \\ [0.8cm] Supervisor Hans Muster3
     \\ [0.5cm] Institute for Abc \\ University of Abc}


\clearpage
\maketitle{}
\thispagestyle{empty} %no page number on first page %
\renewcommand\abstractname{Abstract}
\renewcommand\tablename{Table}
\newpage


\begin{abstract}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
blablabla
\end{abstract}

%\skip{}
\tableofcontents{}
\pagestyle{plain}
\newpage


\section{Introduction}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please make your code into a compilable document. If I add `\end{document}`, it still doesn't compile without errors. For example, `subcaption` is incompatible with `subfigure`, `\maketitle` does not take an argument and I'm still getting errors after correcting those problems. ***Pay attention to the error messages you are getting.*** This will save you time and effort in the end as you will avoid piling up potential problems which you'll have to then disentangle later (probably).

Comment: I am curious, why are you redefining all things back to english?

Answer (score 3):

KOMA-Script includes extensive formatting commands which allow you to easily customise layout and formatting *provided you do not override the facilities by loading packages which overwrite the commands*. For example, `titling` interferes with the customisation of the title.

Below, I use the `titlepage` option to get a title page and KOMA's commands to customise the font used for section headings and titling elements. If you don't like `\titlehead`, consider using `\title` and `\subtitle` instead.

These changes allow the document to compile without errors, at least, although I also had to comment out some incompatible packages.

Note that neither `\maketitle` nor `\tableofcontents` take an argument although KOMA redefines the former, at least, to take an optional argument specifying the page number.

You would probably be better off not using `a4wide`, as well.

Take a look at the excellent documentation for the KOMA-Script classes to find straightforward ways of customising things further. Note that there is an example similar to what you need on page 63 which might be a better way of setting up your title page than your current use of date.

It is a false efficiency to stick to trial-and-error when it isn't doing what you want (and sometimes even when it is). You will save time in the end if you take just a little bit of time to get familiar with the documentation. (I don't mean read it all - just get a sense of what is there and what is possible.) The nice thing about KOMA is that you have a fairly self-contained set of commands and environments which makes it easier to orientate yourself.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,abstracton,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{caption}
\addto\captionsngerman{%
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,amsbsy,latexsym}
%\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} %Chemie-Package
\providecommand{\e}[1]{\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}
%\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage{enumerate,url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{a4wide}
% \usepackage{titling}% better to use koma script's facilities for this if you are using that class
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents} %only functioning when babel not used
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\addto\captionsngerman{%
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{array}
% \usepackage{subcaption}% cannot be used with subfigure
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

%% Control the fonts and formatting used in the table of contents.
% \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

%% Aesthetic spacing redefined
% \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{}
% \setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{title}{\huge\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{titlehead}{\LARGE\centering}

\begin{document}

\titlehead{Abc}
\title{AbcAbc}
\author{Hans Muster \and Hans Muster2}
\date{{Date 2014} \\ [0.8cm] Supervisor Hans Muster3
     \\ [0.5cm] Institute for Abc \\ University of Abc}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} %no page number on first page %
\renewcommand\abstractname{Abstract}
\renewcommand\tablename{Table}


\begin{abstract}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
blablabla
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{plain}
\newpage

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image: Layout]